# Cannot place center while using multirow

Tags: tables, multirow

I cannot make "Beda Maju", "Beda Mundur", and "Beda Pusat" vertically centered. How do I do this?

If I change `*` in `\multirow{2}{*}` to `\multirow{2}{2.5cm}`, the problem is not fixed.

Here is my code.

```
\begin{table}[h]
    \centering
    \caption{Tabel Turunan Numerik Beda Hingga}
    \label{tabelbedahingga}
    \resizebox{\textwidth}{!}{
        \begin{tabular}{|c|c|c|c|}
            \hline
            \rowcolor{green!10}
            \multicolumn{2}{|c|}{Beda Hingga}&Rumus&Orde Kesalahan\\
            \hline
            \multirow{2}{*}{Beda Maju}&Turunan Pertama&$y'_i =\dfrac{y_{i+1}-y_{i}}{h}$&$O(h)$\\
            \cline{2-3}
            &Turunan Kedua&$y''_i =\dfrac{y_{i+2}-2y_{i+1}+y_i}{h^2}$&$O(h)$\\
            \hline
            \multirow{2}{*}{Beda Mundur}&Turunan Pertama&$y'_i=\dfrac{y_{i}-y_{i-1}}{h}$&$O(h)$\\
            \cline{2-3}
            &Turunan Kedua&$y''_i =\dfrac{y_{i}-2y_{i-1}+y_{i-2}}{h^2}$&$O(h)$\\
            \hline
            \multirow{3}{*}{Beda Pusat} &Turunan Pertama&$y'_i=\dfrac{y_{i+1}-y_{i-1}}{2h}$&$O(h^2)$\\
            \cline{2-3}
            &\multirow{2}{*}{Turunan Kedua}&$y''_i =\dfrac{y_{i+2}-2y_{i}+y_{i-2}}{4h^2}$&$O(h^2)$\\
            \cline{3-3}
            &&$y''_i =\dfrac{y_{i+1}-2y_{i}+y_{i-1}}{h^2}$&$O(h^2)$\\
            \hline
        \end{tabular}
    }
\end{table}
```

[image]

Comment: You want them to be vertically centred, if I understand well?

Comment: Yes, vertically centered.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I suppose you want the multirows contents vertically centred, which can be done by trial and error using the vertical move optional argument.

I added some padding to the cells with the `cellspace` package, and a more sensible spacing between caption and table with the `caption` package.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{multirow, caption}
\usepackage{cellspace}
\setlength{\cellspacetoplimit}{4pt}
\setlength{\cellspacebottomlimit}{4pt}
\usepackage[table]{xcolor}

\begin{document}

\begin{table}[h]
    \centering
    \caption{Tabel Turunan Numerik Beda Hingga}
    \label{tabelbedahingga}
        \begin{tabular}{|c|c|Sc|Sc|}
            \hline
            \rowcolor{green!10}
            \multicolumn{2}{|c|}{Beda Hingga}&Rumus&Orde Kesalahan\\
            \hline
            \multirow{2}{*}[-1.6ex]{Beda Maju}&Turunan Pertama&$y'_i =\dfrac{y_{i+1}-y_{i}}{h}$&$O(h)$\\
            \cline{2-3}
            &Turunan Kedua&$y''_i =\dfrac{y_{i+2}-2y_{i+1}+y_i}{h^2}$&$O(h)$\\
            \hline
            \multirow{2}{*}[-1.6ex]{Beda Mundur}&Turunan Pertama&$y'_i=\dfrac{y_{i}-y_{i-1}}{h}$&$O(h)$\\
            \cline{2-3}
            &Turunan Kedua&$y''_i =\dfrac{y_{i}-2y_{i-1}+y_{i-2}}{h^2}$&$O(h)$\\
            \hline
            \multirow{3}{*}[-3.5ex]{Beda Pusat} &Turunan Pertama&$y'_i=\dfrac{y_{i+1}-y_{i-1}}{2h}$&$O(h^2)$\\
            \cline{2-3}
            &\multirow{2}{*}[-1.7ex]{Turunan Kedua}&$y''_i =\dfrac{y_{i+2}-2y_{i}+y_{i-2}}{4h^2}$&$O(h^2)$\\
            \cline{3-3}
            &&$y''_i =\dfrac{y_{i+1}-2y_{i}+y_{i-1}}{h^2}$&$O(h^2)$\\
            \hline
        \end{tabular}
\end{table}

    \end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you very much, @Bernard ! That's what I want..

Answer (score 2):

Vertical centering of cell contents is not a trivial issue.

The previous answer just solves the problem by using manual adjustment.
Another approach could be lying about the row number in the `\multirow` statements. It is shown below.

This also solves the cosmetic matter. However, in my opinion they are not satisfactory solutions, and I would love a general method to do this.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{multirow,cellspace,caption}
\usepackage[table]{xcolor}
\usepackage{graphicx}

\setlength{\cellspacetoplimit}{4pt}
\setlength{\cellspacebottomlimit}{4pt}

\begin{document}
\begin{table}[h]
    \centering
    \caption{Tabel Turunan Numerik Beda Hingga}
    \label{tabelbedahingga}
        \begin{tabular}{|c|c|Sc|c|}
        \hline
        \rowcolor{green!10}
        \multicolumn{2}{|c|}{Beda Hingga} & Rumus & Orde Kesalahan\\
        \hline
        \multirow{3}{*}{Beda Maju}
            & Turunan Pertama & $y'_i =\dfrac{y_{i+1}-y_{i}}{h}$&$O(h)$\\
            \cline{2-3}
            & Turunan Kedua & $y''_i =\dfrac{y_{i+2}-2y_{i+1}+y_i}{h^2} $ & $O(h)$ \\
        \hline
        \multirow{3}{*}{Beda Mundur}
            & Turunan Pertama & $y'_i=\dfrac{y_{i}-y_{i-1}}{h}$&$O(h)$\\
            \cline{2-3}
            & Turunan Kedua & $y''_i =\dfrac{y_{i}-2y_{i-1}+y_{i-2}}{h^2}$&$O(h)$\\
        \hline
        \multirow{5}{*}{Beda Pusat}
            & Turunan Pertama & $y'_i=\dfrac{y_{i+1}-y_{i-1}}{2h}$&$O(h^2)$\\
            \cline{2-3}
            & \multirow{3}{*}{Turunan Kedua} 
                & $y''_i =\dfrac{y_{i+2}-2y_{i}+y_{i-2}}{4h^2}$&$O(h^2)$\\
                \cline{3-3}
            &   & $y''_i =\dfrac{y_{i+1}-2y_{i}+y_{i-1}}{h^2}$&$O(h^2)$\\
        \hline
        \end{tabular}
\end{table}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Thank you for helping me, @e_moro

Answer (score 1):

If your are willing to change to another tabular package, the package [cals](https://ctan.org/pkg/cals) will make it easy to construct the tabular your are asking for:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath, nccmath, caption, CALS}
\usepackage[table]{xcolor}
\usepackage{nccmath}

\let\nc=\nullcell   %Shortcuts
\let\sc=\spancontent

\begin{document}

\begin{table}
    \centering
    \caption{Tabel Turunan Numerik Beda Hingga}
    \label{tabelbedahinggaga}
\begin{calstable}

% Define four columns relative to margin, makes it easy to find correct tabular width
\colwidths{{\dimexpr(\columnwidth/40* 7)\relax}
            {\dimexpr(\columnwidth/40* 9)\relax}
            {\dimexpr(\columnwidth/40* 13)\relax}
            {\dimexpr(\columnwidth/40* 11)\relax}
        }

% Set up a basic grid
\makeatletter
\def\cals@framers@width{0.8pt}
\def\cals@framecs@width{0.8pt}
\cals@setpadding{Ag}
\cals@setcellprevdepth{Al}
\def\cals@cs@width{0.4pt}
\def\cals@rs@width{0.4pt}

% Tabular starts
% R1 Heading
\thead{\bfseries
\brow
    \def\cals@bgcolor{green!15} % Switch on colour
    \nc{ltb}
    \nc{rtb}\alignC\sc{\vfil Beda Hingga} % Horizontal centering the last until reset
    \cell{\vfil Rumus}
    \cell{\vfil Orde Kesalahan}
    \def\cals@bgcolor{}   % Switch off colour
\erow
\mdseries}
% R2
\brow
    \nc{lrt}
    \cell{\vfil Turunan Pertama}
    \cell{\vfil $y'_i =\dfrac{y_{i+1}-y_{i}}{h}$}
    \def\cals@borderB{0pt}
    \cell{$O(h)$}
    \let\cals@borderB\relax
\erow
 %R3
\brow
    \nc{lrb}\alignC\sc{\vfil Beda Maju}
    \cell{\vfil Turunan Kedua}
    \cell{\vfil $y''_i =\dfrac{y_{i+2}-2y_{i+1}+y_i}{h^2}$}
    \cell{\vfil $O(h)$}
\erow
 %R4
\brow
    \nc{lrt}
    \cell{\vfil Turunan Pertama}
    \cell{\vfil $y'_i=\dfrac{y_{i}-y_{i-1}}{h}$}
    \def\cals@borderB{0pt} % Switch on bottom border
    \cell{\vfil $O(h)$}
    \let\cals@borderB\relax % % Switch off bottom border
\erow
 %R5
\brow
    \nc{lrb}\alignC\sc{\vfil Beda Mundur}
    \cell{\vfil Turunan Kedua}
    \cell{\vfil $y''_i =\dfrac{y_{i}-2y_{i-1}+y_{i-2}}{h^2}$}
    \cell{\vfil $O(h)$}
\erow
 %R6
\brow
    \nc{lrt}
    \cell{\vfil Turunan Pertama}
    \cell{\vfil $y'_i=\dfrac{y_{i+1}-y_{i-1}}{2h}$}
    \def\cals@borderB{0pt} % Switch on bottom border
    \cell{\vfil $O(h^2)$}
    \let\cals@borderB\relax %% Switch off bottom border
\erow
 %R7
\brow
    \nc{lr}
    \nc{lrt}
    \cell{\vfil $y''_i =\dfrac{y_{i+2}-2y_{i}+y_{i-2}}{4h^2}$}
    \def\cals@borderB{0pt}  % Switch off bottom border.
    \cell{\vfil $O(h^2)$}
    \let\cals@borderB\relax % Switch on bottom border
\erow
%R8
\brow
    \nc{lrb}\alignC\sc{\vfil Beda Pusat}
    \nc{lrb}\sc{\vfil Turunan Kedua}
    \cell{\vfil $y''_i =\dfrac{y_{i+1}-2y_{i}+y_{i-1}}{h^2}$}
    \cell{\vfil $O(h^2)$}
\erow

\makeatother
\end{calstable}
\end{table}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Be aware that many lines of code can be removed by defining simple switches that turn on and off colour, line, side bearing etc. Based on an example from the documentation, I have defined a macro that turns colour on and off:

```
\def\green{\ifx\cals@bgcolor\empty      % Colour switch (on-off)
    \def\cals@bgcolor{green!15}
\else \def\cals@bgcolor{} \fi}
```

If you place `\green`before and after the cell, you get a green cell. If you place it at the beginning and end of a row, you have a `\rowcolour`that functions. The on-switch works on all cells in all rows until it is turned off. Be aware that you need to place the line

```
\def\cals@bgcolor{}
```

before you use the macro for the first time.

The macro can be adapted for turning on and of borders and lines (decoration):

```
\def\bb{\ifx\cals@borderB\relax     % Bottom border switch (on of)
    \def\cals@borderB{0pt}
\else \let\cals@borderB\relax\fi}
```

Comment: Thank you very much! @Sveinung